# Execute action on new STAThread

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I execute an action like `window.Close()` on a newly created STAThread?
This is my current code:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        gameCanvas = new GameCanvas(width, height);

        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

        gameCanvas.Closed += (s,e) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);

        Dispatcher.Run();
    });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
```

How should I execute `gameCanvas.close();` 
I've really got no idea I've tried Dispatcher.Invoke but i got a object not set to reference etc etc error

The current project is a Console project and has no other STAThread

Comment: Can you tell us WHY (you don't use a normal WPF application)?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Experimental purposes.

Comment: Well, then experiment away. But you don't call methods 'on a thread', you'll need a reference to an object. Like maybe that canvas. And then myCanvas.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)

Comment: @HenkHolterman How would I call myCanvas.Show() on the canvas I created in the STAThread above? I've thread using myCanvas.dispatcher but I got a object not set error

Comment: @HenkHolterman which is ofcourse obvious because I haven't initiated the Canvas on my main thread but in the STAThread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stash a reference to the thread's `Dispatcher` in a location that is accessible to the initial thread. You can either use a variable for the `Dispatcher` itself, or better yet, a variable for the WPF `Window` as it has a member property for its relevant `Dispatcher`, as this will probably be more useful to you.

I've created an example mimicking your setup here, using a stock WPF `Window` called `MainWindow`. This example runs for about 15 seconds and then calls close. Note that the `windowLock` lock object is just for safe access to the `window` variable.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Object windowLock = new object();
    MainWindow window = null;

    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Dispatcher workerDispatcher = null;
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

        workerDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        lock (windowLock)
        {
            window = new MainWindow();
        }
        window.Closed += (s, e) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
        window.Show();

        Dispatcher.Run();
    });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(15000);

    lock (windowLock)
    {
        if (null != window) // Highly unlikely, but not impossible.
        {
            window.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                window.Close();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your good detailed answer, I've got one question left I'm getting an error at `window.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>` Cannot convert lambda expression to type system.delegate, should I create an Action to fix this? or how should I proceed?

Comment: Nevermind adding (Action) before the () worked Thanks!

Comment: I compiled this in a project targeting .net 4.5; I think the typecast isn't needed there. Sorry about that.

Comment: Np, I should upgrade to 4.5 :p Thanks alot!